# jquery disabled=disabled not working in safari

Tags: jquery

I have some code that disabled a button, using jquery it does:

```
$('#fishID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

This seems to work in every browser (IE6, IE7, 8, 9, Chrome, Firefox) except Safari where it does not disable the button.

Should I be setting it to `'disabled', 'true'` ? What's the difference?

Is there a quirk with Safari that might explain this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in jQuery 1.6+ you should use [`.prop('disabled', true);`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), this should work for all.

Comment: Aha I see - my layman's explanation then is that the attribute is what you have in the markup, the property is whatever is stored in memory. Changing the attribute should not affect whether it is disabled or not, you have to change the property - safari is the only browser that is standards compliant/anal enough to care about this. It's the property you want and that's why this answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, the probably may be jQuery. I believe this is fixed in 1.6.

http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/

Answer (score 0):

I have spent time on this. Here is what I have learned:

1. disabled="disabled" does not work in ie6/7 when you use jQuery to change the attribute dynamically.
2. The only way around this is to clone the select, add the disabled attribute (or remove it), then append back.

Example:

```
//clone dropdown and append for ie support
var _parent = $("#selectElement").parent();
var _clone = $("#selectElement");
$(_clone).attr("disabled","true");
$("#selectElement").remove();
$(_parent).append(_clone);
```